# Android USBOTG write permission error

Tags: android

i have problem with writting to OTG USB.

-tablet Lenovo Yoga 8

-Android 4.4

-write to internal storage(/storage/sdcard0) and external microSD (/storage/sdcard1) working without problem

-path to USB -> /storage/usbotg

-ES File Manager writing to USB without problem

Thank you very much, and sorry my english.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="xx.xxxxx.xxxx"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-sdk
  android:minSdkVersion="19"
  android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 ...
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
 File file = new File("/storage/usb0/report.pdf");
 OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
 document.writeTo(os);
 document.close();
 os.close();
```

Comment: working for me: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2634840

Comment: If you have an answer can you put it in the answer box provided and accept it? Its better than editing the word "solved" into the question.